# How to get posts from Facebook in arabic

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I try this code using Facebook graph to get posts from Facebook Page where the posts in Arabic language but the results shown as hexa
Here is the code

```
var client = new WebClient();
string oauthUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}", "xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxx");
string accessToken = client.DownloadString(oauthUrl).Split('=')[1];
string pagePosts = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/ADEN.IT.page/posts?access_token={0}", accessToken));
Response.Write(pagePosts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

before calling client.DownloadString on your facebook page.
Assuming that the return is really getting the correct content.

EDIT:
Looks like you are getting a JSON Response. For that I unfortunately have to refer you to the facebook documentation on how to deserialize the message.
JSON deserialization in c# itself could then look something like this if facebook provides definitions for the Facebook DataObject :

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookDataObject>(pagePost);
```

EDIT 2:
Maybe this can help:
http://facebooksdk.net/
[Parsing Json facebook c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309391/parsing-json-facebook-c-sharp)

Comment: Try debugging. Take the created string of your string.Format of the facebook link including the accessToken out of the debug window and paste it into a browser. What does the browser show?

Comment: Excuse me what should I add for access token in the browser

Comment: The return value from the line before the downloadString: string accessToken = client.DownloadString(oauthUrl).Split('=')[1];

Comment: Your browser shows the same result? Can you add the result from the browser in your post? copy&paste?

Comment: {
   "data": [
      {
         "message": "\u0627\u0639\u062a\u0642\u062f \u0628\u0639\u0636 \u0648\u0627\u0636\u0639\u0648 \u0645\u0646\u0627\u0647\u062c \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0639\u0644\u064a\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0642\u0644\u064a\u062f\u064a\u0629 \u0623\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0639\u0644\u0648\u0645\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062a\u064a \u064a\u0643\u062a\u0633\u0628\u0647\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0644\u0627\u0645\u064a\u0630 \u062a\u0624\u062f\u0649 \u0625\u0644\u0649 \u062a\u0639\u062f\u064a\u0644 \u0633\u0644\u0648\u0643\u0647\u0645 \u0648\u0647\u0630\u0627 \u062e\u0637\

Comment: Thats a JSON Response. You probably have to refer to the facebook documentation on how to deserialize it. They most likely provide classes if this is the standard way. The code would look something like this: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookDataObject>(pagePost); for an easy Json Conversion.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time